# Can we have split view control in iphone same that is in iPad?

Tags: iphone, split, uisplitviewcontroller

As we can see in youtube and facebook app. there are splits when we select one cell . split is hidden then. i want to have this type of structure in my app. if it is posible that in ios7 they will add template for split view for iphone
. As that worked fine in iPad. Can you please help me, i need to develop an app with this type of structure
[image: facebook app split view]

in iphone when we create project with master template
we have this type of split view...

can we have same thing in iPhone too.
if there is default control of it.
[image: Split view in ipad]

Comment: You should search first on Net before asking here

Comment: this is very rude to devote. i lost 2 points...

Comment: ok how can we know who downvote the question??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there isn't any default controller for applying slide effect inside iPhone.

Yes, you can achieve this by adding custom classes. Checkout for [MFSideMenuContainerViewController](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu)

Enjoy Programming!